# How to transform different groups into time series

Tags: r, time-series

I'm dealing with a time series problem. Here's an extract of my data :

```
head(Dataset)
Project    Date             Budget
  PR1      September 2015     0.2
  PR1      October 2015       0.5
  PR1      November 2015      0.9
  PR1      December 2015      1.2
  PR1      January 2016       1.8
  PR2      August 2015        1.5
  PR2      September 2015     1.9
  PR2      October 2015       2.3
  PR2      December 2015      2.5 
  PR2      January 2016       2.8
```

I have the evolution of the budget for each project and each month, I would like to transform each project's budget evolution into time serie, in order to do classification. 
How can I do that ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Which stationary period do you want? You actually have a time serie with your `Date` column

Comment: I would like to represent the evolution until today, my data starts in 2009. I would like to represent a time serie for each project, is that possible ?

Comment: It depends on the amount of each `Project` you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This transforms the input in the Note at the end to a multivariate time series z.

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(DF, index = "Date", FUN = as.yearmon, format = "%B %Y", 
       split = "Project")
```

giving this zoo object:

```
> z

         PR1 PR2
Aug 2015  NA 1.5
Sep 2015 0.2 1.9
Oct 2015 0.5 2.3
Nov 2015 0.9  NA
Dec 2015 1.2 2.5
Jan 2016 1.8 2.8
```

`as.ts(z)` could be used to get a `ts` object if that were needed.

### Wide form

This is not a time series object but if you wanted a wide form object with year/month along the top then:

```
library(zoo)

DF0 <- transform(DF, Date = format(as.yearmon(Date, "%B %Y"), "%Y-%m"))
xtabs(Budget ~ Project + Date, DF0)
```

giving this xtabs table:

```
       Date
Project 2015-08 2015-09 2015-10 2015-11 2015-12 2016-01
    PR1     0.0     0.2     0.5     0.9     1.2     1.8
    PR2     1.5     1.9     2.3     0.0     2.5     2.8
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "Project,Date,Budget
PR1,September 2015,0.2
PR1,October 2015,0.5
PR1,November 2015,0.9
PR1,December 2015,1.2
PR1,January 2016,1.8
PR2,August 2015,1.5
PR2,September 2015,1.9
PR2,October 2015,2.3
PR2,December 2015,2.5 
PR2,January 2016,2.8"
DF <- read.csv(text = Lines, strip.white = TRUE)
```